# php email send to multiple address not working

Tags: php

Hi friends why this is not working ? While doing print_r , $emails ( which is To) is not showing any emails. It's fine when i send to only one person.

```
$mails = array('abc@gmail.com','123@email.com');
$emails = implode(",",$mails);

$from= 'abc@imail.com);
$subject = 'hello';
$body = 'test';
send_email($from,$emails,$body,$subject);
```

Comment: Uhh... are you sure this is the code you're using? There is not `send_email` function and your script contains a syntax error.

Comment: @lekensteyn , it works with one mail, ie function is working

Comment: @sagarmatha : show us your `send_email` function, and try to post real code instead of a rewrite, which would prevent people posting about syntax errors that aren't in your original script.

Comment: @JapanPro: @lekensteyn is right - the code, as shown, has a syntax error and calls a function which is not part of the standard PHP, and has not been explained by the OP. Look closer.

Comment: @Lucanos send_email can be a custom function , inside that mail function can be there.

Comment: @JapanPro, we cannot know what happens in that `send_email` function. Maybe it's not using `mail()` at all, and a custom class which does not accept multiple addresses.

Comment: Thanks all, It did work now. I did create a custom function. I made this to send newsletters.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to

```
$mails = array('abc@gmail.com','123@email.com');
foreach($mails as $k=>$m){
  $mails =trim($mails[$k]);
}
$emails = trim(implode(", ",$mails));

$from= 'abc@imail.com';
$subject = 'hello';
$body = 'test';
send_email($from,$emails,$body,$subject);
```